# Using Java Request Sampler inside a ForEach controller in Jmeter

Tags: foreach, jmeter

I am Trying to use a **Java request Sampler** inside a **ForEach** Controller.

This is my custom Sampler

```
public class ClientSampler extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

    String Name;

    @Override
    public Arguments getDefaultParameters() {
        Arguments defaultParameters = new Arguments();
        defaultParameters.addArgument("name", "Tarek");
        return defaultParameters;
    }

    @Override
    public void setupTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
        Name = context.getParameter("name");
    }

    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {   
        System.out.println(Name);
    }
}
```

in Jmeter I create **user defined variables** with 5 variables:

[image]

And a **ForEach Controller**:

[image]

then added the java request as a **child** to ForEach controller:

[image]

the Test plan is the following:

[image]

when I start the test the output is:

```
first
first
first
first
first
```

expected:

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
```

even if I set the **start and end indexes** in the ForEach controller the result is the same.

using an http sampler inside the ForEach controller works great, but when using a Java requests the result is not as expected.

Can anyone explain why I am getting this output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem is because I misunderstood how it works:

Jmeter calls `SetupTest(JavaSamplerContext context)` once before the Test starts and calls `runTest(JavaSamplerContext context)` in each loop (I though it calls SetupTest also at the beginning of each loop).

so I just added

```
Name = context.getParameter("name");
```

inside runTest and now the result is exactly how it should be.

```
@Override
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {   
    Name = context.getParameter("name");        
    System.out.println(Name);
}
```